# I have a for loop that generates different pandas dataframes whose values I want to save sequentially

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I made a for loop that creates a different pandas dataframe on each iteration. Something like this ->
First iteration:

| index | Letter | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 1 |
| 1 | B | 2 |
| 2 | C | 3 |

Second iteration:

| index | Letter | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | C | 5 |
| 1 | D | 3 |
| 2 | E | 1 |
| 3 | F | 2 |

Third iteration:

| index | Letter | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 2 |
| 1 | F | 1 |

I want to save each dataframe to a new one that looks like this:

| index | Letter | Value | Value | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 1 |  | 2 |
| 1 | B | 2 |  |  |
| 2 | C | 3 | 5 |  |
| 3 | D |  | 3 |  |
| 4 | E |  | 1 |  |
| 5 | F |  | 2 | 1 |

Also, new letters can appear on each iteration, so for example if 'G' appears for the first time on interation 'n', a new row would need to be created on the desired consolidated dataframe.

Comment: I believe you’ve forgotten to ask a *question*.

Comment: Do you have the final table and what to add in a new row? with an extra column as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `Letter` the index for each dataframe, and then use `pd.concat` with `axis=1`:

```
dataframes = [df1, df2, df3]
new_df = pd.concat([d.set_index('Letter') for d in dataframes], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
        Value  Value  Value
Letter                     
A       1.0   NaN     2.0  
B       2.0   NaN    NaN   
C       3.0    5.0   NaN   
D      NaN     3.0   NaN   
E      NaN     1.0   NaN   
F      NaN     2.0    1.0
```